# Fancy Tree, clicking on different nodes auto collapses other selected nodes and sub nodes

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I render  a list which is transformed by Fancy Tree in a Jquery Dialog Box.  I notice that if I select a sub node and close the tree meaning un-expand its parent node and close the dialog box. When I re-open the dialogbox when I click on a different node, I see that the other selected node will automatically expand and then un-expand.

```
$("#errorCodes").fancytree({
    activeVisible: false, // Make sure, active nodes are visible (expanded).
    aria: false, // Enable WAI-ARIA support.
    autoActivate: false, // Automatically activate a node when it is focused (using keys).
    autoCollapse: false, // Automatically collapse all siblings, when a node is expanded.
    autoScroll: false, // Automatically scroll nodes into visible area.
    clickFolderMode: 3, // 1:activate, 2:expand, 3:activate and expand, 4:activate (dblclick expands)
    checkbox: false, // Show checkboxes.
    debugLevel: 0, // 0:quiet, 1:normal, 2:debug
    disabled: false, // Disable control
    generateIds: false, // Generate id attributes like <span id='fancytree-id-KEY'>
    idPrefix: "ft_", // Used to generate node id´s like <span id='fancytree-id-<key>'>.
    icons: false, // Display node icons.
    keyboard: true, // Support keyboard navigation.
    keyPathSeparator: "/", // Used by node.getKeyPath() and tree.loadKeyPath().
    minExpandLevel: 1, // 1: root node is not collapsible
    selectMode: 1, // 1:single, 2:multi, 3:multi-hier
    tabbable: false, // Whole tree behaves as one single control
    titlesTabbable: false // Node titles can receive keyboard focus
});
errorTree = $("#errorCodes").fancytree("getTree");

$("input[name=searchErrors]").keyup(function (e) {
    var match = $(this).val();
    if (e && e.which === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE || $.trim(match) === "") {
        $("button#btnResetSearchErrors").click();
        return;
    }

    var n = errorTree.applyFilter(match);
    $("button#btnResetSearchErrors").attr("disabled", false);
    $("span#matchesErrors").text("(" + n + " Results)");
}).focus();

$("button#btnResetSearchErrors").click(function (e) {
    $("input[name=searchErrors]").val("");
    $("span#matchesErrors").text("");
    errorTree.clearFilter();
}).attr("disabled", true);

$("input#hideModeErrors").change(function (e) {
    errorTree.options.filter.mode = $(this).is(":checked") ? "hide" : "dimm";
    errorTree.clearFilter();
    $("input[name=searchErrors]").keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by downloading the latest version of FancyTree which is 2.3.0.  The issue was when click on a node and used check it, it used to become the active row. So if were expanding another root node, it used to automatically expand the node where the active row was.